# .app file not get install using package installer

Tags: xcode

I have created a package installer using Xcode's PackageMaker. I want to install a .app file into the applications folder, but when i am running installer package, it's showing that the software is installed succesfully. When i checked the applications folder, the application i m installing is not there. Can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

While the Installer is still running you can select the Window menu and choose the Installer Log option. In the Installer Log dialog select the 'Show All Logs' from the drop down control. This might help you determine where the Installer put your .app or what happened.

BTW I'm seeing the same thing with a .pkg I have written and would love to hear if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting things working with my .pkg by making it install into /Applications/ with the trailing slash. I had previously been just using /Applications. Maybe that works for your package?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the installer can upgrade packages even if their not located in /Applications. So if there is an application with the same name or it already exists on your hard drive it will try and install over that. To fix it click on the item your trying to install in the content pane then click on the components tab and make sure the "allow relocation" check box is unchecked. Should work perfect after that